# Microsoft Access Equivalent of "Create Table #Tablename"?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm wanting to create a temporary table, purely to make a simpler user interface feature, and it has to be visible only to the current user. I can't see how to achieve this in Access: apparently the "create" in Access is not like the standard SQL: there is a "Temporary" option however (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177893(v=office.12).aspx):

> "When a TEMPORARY table is created it is visible only within the
>   session in which it was created. It is automatically deleted when the
>   session is terminated. Temporary tables can be accessed by more than
>   one user."

It's that last sentence that I have a problem with. I can see "normal databases" you would use SQL "create table #whatever"... so I want to imitate that with Access.

It's a bit long winded to explain the whole situation, apologies if i'm not being clear enough as I'm trying to avoid writing a stupid amount of unnecessary detail: essentially what I have is an "employee" record with a number of "tasks" they perform. My "EmployeeTasks" table has a "percentage" field for each task (i.e. in plain english "employee A(f.key) performs task B(f.key) X% of the day".

To maintain that information in the user interface, it's a bit "messy" to ask users to manually enter percentages... to my mind, people don't really think "well I work 7.6 hours a day, i do 10 tasks, i do this task 3.528% of the time, this task 9.813% of the time... " etc... What I want to present to the user, is their list of tasks, (in a continuous form) with their task effort expressed as hours and minutes per day.

So my theory is, create a temporary table including hours and minute extrapolation, display a form based on that table, the user can then edit those hours and minutes, and "update" function will take those figures and convert back to percentages based on sum. This way the user doesn't have to worry about being accurate in assuring all hours and minutes add to 7.6 hours, and the don't have to worry about all percentages adding to 1 etc... There's a large acceptable margin of error (because obviously most people don't perform tasks for a regimented amount of time, we're only gathering rough information)

It seems the easiest approach is to create a form based on a temp table [EDIT ADDITION]: but if more than one user edits a different employee, they would be overwriting each others temporary tables unless I can create a user-unique table somehow [/EDIT]. Another method I guess would be to dynamically create a list of controls for each task and read from them, but that would get messy quickly when employees have a large number of tasks. Thanks for your help, Simon

Comment: Data is usually best stored in its original state, that way you know what you started with, you know what you did to it after that, and you know what you ended up with. Modifying data before storage means you are left with just 1/2 the story, and I can promise that at some point in the future, this will cause you a major headache which you didn't foresee. Additionally, if the modification which you apply to the data needs alteration in the future, then you aren't left up the proverbial creek.

Store the data as it gets entered, then filter it through the algorithms you need for reporting.

Comment: That's good advice... I guess with my data I've got a few tables with percentages as well as employees with different "FTE" figures (full time equivelent) i.e. employee A works full time (1FTE), B works 0.5 (.5FTE) ... And i'm combining that not only with tasks, but for business units they service "employee A with FTE B works X percentage on Task C, and with Task C works Y percentage servicing Business D". If I stored that as hours and minutes rather than percentages, if the employee ever changed FTE, or changed Task split etc I'd have to feed all other data through an algorithm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that Access SQL does not support `CREATE TABLE #TableName` to create session-specific temporary tables like T-SQL does, but practically speaking it doesn't need to. Here's why:

---

For your Microsoft Access database application to support multiple concurrent users

1. you ***must*** split your database into a **front-end** database file (containing queries, forms, reports, code) linked to a **back-end** database file (containing just the data tables), and
2. each user ***must*** have their own (local) copy of the front-end database file.

No two users should ever *directly* open the same .mdb or .accdb file at the same time, e.g., by double-clicking it or doing `File > Open` in Access. (More details [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html)).

---

Your VBA code in the front-end can create a temporary table in the front-end and your application can use it. Access allows us to build queries that JOIN local tables with linked tables, so the (local) temporary table can be used like a #Temporary table in T-SQL.

Since each user has their own copy of the front-end file (point #2, above), they each have their own copy of any temporary tables that your application might create.

Comment: mm true I had conveniently (or inconveniently) forgotten about that requirement :) I don't think I'll go down that road because I will only have 2 or 3 concurrent users... but yours is good advice. I think I'll just concatenate the current userID or NTID on to the new table name and go down the "local/backend" road at a later date. Readers: don't do what I do, do what Gord says!! :)